# Vue.js: Components vs. Plugins vs. Mixins

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

What exactly are the differences between the following (when to use what):

- Vue Components
- Vue Plugins
- Vue Mixins

Comment: This looks like it addresses your question:
https://medium.com/@denny.headrick/mixins-and-plugins-in-vuejs-ecee9b37d1bd
Also the official docs:
https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html
https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Components are elements. They are like Blocks of functionality and layout that you would use to build an application or UI. Components can be extended, doing so uses aspects of the original component while giving you the ability to add other functionality.

Similar to extending existing component, you can use a mixin, which is much like a component you'd extend, but it adds functionality to an existing component.

A plugin adds top-level functionality that can be accessed by any component.

---

The use depends on what you're trying to achieve. Things like routes and state management are a good fit for plugin, because it allows you to affect/listen to changes across the application without setting up props or listeners. But you wouldn't use them for a component-specific functionality, because they would pollute your app.

Mixins is a controversial feature that some argue should not be used. The idea is that Component wrapping or Higher Order Components can implement in a more robust way. more info here:(https://reactjs.org/blog/2016/07/13/mixins-considered-harmful.html)

The components are fundamental to building a vue app, so you can't get around using them, but there are ways you can get more out of them. Vue allows use of slots, which help cover some of the functionality, that the react community prefers higher order components does.

If you're relatively new to Vue, I would advise that you don't use mixins, hold off on Plugins until, and spend time with implementing functionality using components and if you're creating re-usable components utilise scoped slots.  https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  Just learning Vue.js.  A bit of clarification: In order to have my component used by someone else, do I need to change/expose my component as plugin?  If not, how would they import/use my component in their project.

Comment: you can share the component code only. Components are self contained to some degree that way, but they may require libraries and some steps to implement; but the common way is to package the libraries for inclusion as a dependency. You can browse the many github vue library repos to see examples of how this is done. They often include the code and the build process to generate a library for distribution. The choice depends on your needs and experience though. You can also just share a working project repo if you're sharing with a colleague or team member.